# How to get python to recognize a scale bar and set the dimensions of the image

Tags: python

I have simple script that loads in an image that has a vertical and horizontal scale bar in the lower left corner (vertical scale is first column of pixels) and horizontal scale bar is a line on the first row of pixels.

My script then looks at that and I set the dimensions however half the time I export images it works, the other half of the time I get the error "float division by zero" because I think it does not see the first row or somehow adding an extra row.

Any help would be MORE than appreciated! Below is an example of the code for the vertical scale bar. I do the same steps for the horizontal scale bar

```
s = mpimg.imread(r'C:\Users\XDF\Desktop\ScaleTest.tif')
vbar_len = 10.0 # length of vertical scale bar in meters
vscale = vbar_len/len(s[:,0,0][s[:,0,0]==0]) # vertical scale in meters / pixel
print (v_scale)
```

[image: Example image and you can see the scale bars on the lower left corner]

Comment: Are all your images tiff format? Any kind of compression can change colours so that things that were previously solid black come out as non-zero.

Comment: You may want to check `s[:,0,0]` for a couple of files.

Comment: Turns out that yes the images were getting padded so I set up a template and now the exported images work great. Thanks!